# Which regular expression to use to exclude certain ending in string?

Tags: python, regex

I have two slugs, but I only to capture just one. But I struggle to exclude the second which just has an added `#` plus some text.

Here are the two slugs:

```
slugs = ['/sub/12345678', '/sub/12345678#is']
```

And here is what I tried with Python's `re`:

```
cleaned_slugs = []
for i in slugs:
    slug_check = re.match('/sub/[0-9]{8}[^#]', i).group(0)
    cleaned_slug.append(slug_check)
```

When I try out this regex on [Pythex](https://pythex.org/), it selects just the first slug.

What do I get wrong?

*Btw: I know that the `for` loop is not the most elegant way. I appreciate any shorter answer…*

Comment: Instead of `[^#]`, just make sure the 8 digits are "anchored" to the end of the string with `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want sub included and just the one without the "#":

```
slugs = ['/sub/12345678', '/sub/12345678#is']
cleaned_slugs = []
for i in slugs:
    patt= re.search(r'/sub/[0-9]{8}$', i)
    if patt:
        cleaned_slugs.append(patt.group()) 
cleaned_slugs
['/sub/12345678']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that the string ends after the digits:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('/sub/(\d+)$')
>>> slugs = ['/sub/12345678', '/sub/12345678#is']
>>> for slug in slugs:
...    match = pattern.search(slug)
...    if match:
...        print match.group(1)
... 
12345678
```

Here `$` matches the end of the string.

FYI, I've intentionally used `\d+` instead of `[0-9]{8}` since I doubt you really need to check for exactly 8 digits since it is a slug. If though you want to do this, just replace `\d+` with the `[0-9]{8}`.

Also, check this thread for a shorter way of getting the captured group: [Getting captured group in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366848/getting-captured-group-in-one-line).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and advice! I could follow it nearly as well as @Padraic Cunningham's answer. I upvoted it as well, but slightly found the other answer more applicable to my case.

Comment: @MartinBetz you are welcome, never mind, just glad it helped, thanks for explaining your choice.

Answer (score 1):

how about just this?

```
 print [s for s in slugs if '#' not in s]
```

or, equivalently,

```
 print filter(lambda s: '#' not in s, slugs)
```

Comment: Good idea, and I upvoted it, but I depend on re.match and chose the other answer as best answer. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

As you say the `for` here is totally unnecessary, just `filter`

```
reg = re.compile('/sub/(\d+)$')
slugs = ['/sub/12345678', '/sub/12345678#is']
cleaned_slug = filter( lambda s: reg.match(s), slugs )
```